# jQuery targeting inside of a div

Tags: jquery

I have a form where I want to show an input box when an option is selected.

**The problem:** I am allowing users to add more form elements dynamically, so the id's count up, and I'm not sure how to target the current form input, and not every single one.

**As an example, after a user adds a 2nd form item I have something similar to this:**

```
<div class="option-wrapper">
    <div id="condition-1" class="condition">
      <select id="option-1" class="option">
          <option value="0">Select...</option>
          <option value="1">Option One</option>
          <option value="2">Option Two</option>
      </select>
      <select id="operator-1" class="operator">
          <option value="0">Select...</option>
          <option value="1">greater than</option>
          <option value="2">less than</option>
      </select>
      <div id="input-1" class="form-input" style="display:none;">
          <input id="form-input-1" class="form-input"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="option-wrapper">
    <div id="condition-2" class="condition">
      <select id="option-1" class="option">
          <option value="0">Select...</option>
          <option value="1">Option One</option>
          <option value="2">Option Two</option>
      </select>
      <select id="operator-2" class="operator">
          <option value="0">Select...</option>
          <option value="1">greater than</option>
          <option value="2">less than</option>
      </select>
      <div id="input-2" class="form-input" style="display:none;">
          <input id="form-input-2" class="form-input"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Trying to target #input-2 to show it**, by using form-input. Only want to show it for the current option-wrapper, inside the wrapper the user is currently working in.

**Currently trying:**

```
$('.operator').change(function() {
switch (this.value) {
    case '0':
        break;
    case '1':
        $(this).parents('.form-input').toggle();
        break;
}
});
```

I know this use of parents is wrong, I've tried a lot of variations and haven't been able to hit the one I wanted. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:?

```
$('.operator').change(function() {
    if (this.value === 1) 
            $('.form-input:last').toggle();
});
```

Or If got you wrong, you might want this:

```
$('.operator').change(function() {
    if (this.value === 1) 
            $(this).parent().find('.form-input').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Because they can continue to add more form items, .option-wrapper. And becuase they can work in operator-1 or operator-2, targeting the last item will not work consistently. Need this to work so that if they change operator-1 it shows input-1, hopefully thats more clear, thanks!

Comment: @VisioN. Read the DOM again... nope. (the input has the same class, maybe he needs to select him as well...)

Comment: @gdoron `.operator` has a sibling element with class `.form-input`. Hasn't it? And input element is not hidden by default :P

Comment: @VisioN. but it has a son... (what's his class name? You got it `form-input`) :)

Comment: Son obviously doesn't need to be toggled :)

Comment: @VisioN. I don't know... depends on what he's doing, but you're probably right.

Comment: So yours toggles two elements and mine toggles the needed element. Heeeeeence, mine is better :P

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$(this).siblings(".form-input").toggle();
```

It gets the sibling element with class `.form-input`.

Comment: `.form-input` isn't a sibling of it's parent.

Comment: Yes... `this` is the `<select>` not the `<option>`.

Comment: Yes, I copied that `parents` from the example :)

Comment: Next time copy mine(but not my first options as I'm off then...) `LOL`

Answer (score -1):

I guess when you select .form-input you'll end up with at least 2 elements: the div and the input. With one do will show? Could you try this?

```
 $(this).parent().find('.form-input')[0].toggle();
```

Comment: Check, your script won't work, since `[0]` takes the HTMLElement object but not JQuery object.